# How to test installation on non dev domain

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm developing a google apps marketplace app. There's the `Test install flow` button on the dashboard, but I'd like to test installation on another domain of ours - to see that permissions, token etc. work as expected. Is there a way to install an (it's non published yet) on a domain which is not related to development?

Comment: No sure why this question was downvoted, an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, this was surprisingly straightforward, but it worked for me:

Open two browser windows, one for your dev account (dev.com) and one for the domain you wish to test on (test.com)

- In you dev account, go to the dashboard and click the `Test installation flow` button
- In the popup that you get, go to the address bar and copy the link
- Now go to the browser with your test.com domain, and enter this address
- You'll be asked to login, and then you'll get the consent screen
- You should now see the app in your test.com`s marketplace apps list

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a new application in the chrome web store.

Make sure that you create this application in the web store with an account that belongs to the given domain. Next, restrict access to your domain.

Finally, you can install the application on the domain.

Comment: So if my dev domain is X and I want to install it on domain Y, I need to publish the app with domain Y?

Comment: if you want to install on domain "test.com" then you must create a chrome store app with an account SOMEBODY@test.com to test deployment to "test.com".

Comment: So there is no way to test installation on "arbitrary.com" without creating an app with that domain first?

Comment: Exactly. it is quite tedious.